# Synerty Attune, SSH Steps are slow to run

Tags: ssh

I'm using the Attune script automation server, and my SSH steps take a while to run, even when they are simple steps.

The target server is not connected to the internet, and my test command is

```
date
```

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Comment: This is pretty vague. How slow is it? How are the ssh client and server configured?  Perhaps you could run `ssh -vv` to collect debugging info and note where the long pauses are?